# inserting the new json data in the already existing json list

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, list

am trying to insert the json data into another json data list data using update function

datasets:

```
data = {'name':{'first' : 'xx', 'last': 'yy'}, 'class': {'standard': '5', 'section': '6'}}   

maindata = [{'school': {'govt':{ 'value':'public1', 'item':'zphs1'}, 'convent':{'value':'private1','item':'HPS1'}}}, 
            {'school': {'govt':{ 'value':'public2', 'item':'zphs2'}, 'convent':{'value':'private2','item':'HPS2'}}}]
```

Trying to fit in the data into main data after the tag, 'school'

expected output:

```
maindata = [{'school': {'govt':{ 'value':'public1', 'item':'zphs1'}, 'convent':{'value':'private1','item':'HPS1'}, 'name':{'first' : 'xx', 'last': 'yy'}, 'class': {'standard': '5', 'section': '6'}}}, 
            {'school': {'govt':{ 'value':'public2', 'item':'zphs2'}, 'convent':{'value':'private2','item':'HPS2'},'name':{'first' : 'xx', 'last': 'yy'}, 'class': {'standard': '5', 'section': '6'}}}]
```

code used:

```
for i in maindata:
i['school'].update(data)
```

which returns None

Comment: In the latter code example, should the `i['school']` line be indented?

Answer (score 2):

The dictionary update method is not expected to return anything. It performs an in-place update that mutates the target dictionary. To see what this returns, try looking at the content of maindata after the update has run.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct: the `maindata` dictionary is being updated. After making the following update:

```
for i in maindata:
    i['school'].update(data)
```

check the value of `maindata`, it should be exactly what you're expecting it to be. You can also verify this by doing the following:

```
desired_output = [
    {'school': {'govt':{ 'value':'public1', 'item':'zphs1'}, 'convent':{'value':'private1','item':'HPS1'}, 'name':{'first' : 'xx', 'last': 'yy'}, 'class': {'standard': '5', 'section': '6'}}},
    {'school': {'govt':{ 'value':'public2', 'item':'zphs2'}, 'convent' {'value':'private2','item':'HPS2'},'name':{'first' : 'xx', 'last': 'yy'}, 'class': {'standard': '5', 'section': '6'}}}
]

for i in maindata:
    i['school'].update(data)

maindata == desired_output
```

That works for me.